# How to study the separate effect of a variable?

Tags: regression, research-design

Suppose I have a relationship between 3 variables:

A = B + C

and that I know that B and C are related with an other variable D that has opposite effect on B and C:
Increasing D will increase B but decrease C.

Now if I regress A on D (D=IV), D has a strong negative effect on A. So I can desume that the negative effect of D on C are stronger than the positive effect of D on B.

How could I study the separate effect of D on A?